# Aggregate old blog data into a new blogging service

Tags: blog, migration

Over the course of many years, I have managed to create blogs on many different sites: Xanga, LJ, and Myspace.  How can one go about taking the data from these services and moving it to a new service, ie Blogspot (which may not even be that new)

Comment: It would be easiest if you replaced the "etc" in your question with the actual blogs, and specified an exact service you want to move it to.  Otherwise the combinations are too big, and there aren't any "blog post" xml standards that I know of besides RSS for example...

Comment: per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no standard export file from your old blog, and an import routine in the new blog system that can work with it, the only idea I can think of is getting the old blogs RSS feed (assuming you can make it give an RSS of all the posts, something that is not always possible).
You will lose all your comments BTW.

I know that WordPress (the self-hosted version, that is wordpress.org) has a system (the plugin FeedWordPress) that will allow you to import an RSS feed into a new WordPress blog.

Then from there on you could export the WordPress file into the most common system that exists today.

A lot of work for you...

Good luck,
Tal

Answer (score 1):

There are no general rules for doing this. It is all in the hands of the blog platform developers, blog platform supporters or in yours.

For example, if your target blog is Wordpress, you can take a look at this page: [Wordpress » Importing Content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content).

For this reason is really important to choose carefully the platform where you plan to initiate a new blog.